# Check if a function could be used in the with-statement as context-expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

```
with context_expression [as target]:
    with-body
```

As we know, the `context_expression` should return a context manager object.

BTW, I tried to connect to a `postgresql` database by using `psycopg2` in this with-statement. I didn't use `contextlib.closing()`, and it still connected successfully：

```
with psycopg2.connect(dbname='db', user='zzz') as conn:
      cur = conn.cursor()
```

`psycopg2.connect()` doesn't have methods like `__enter__()` and `__exit__()`.

Questions:

1. Why this with-statement works?
2. Is there a way to check if a function or an expression could return a context manager object?
3. What is the difference if I use`contextlib.closing()`?

   ```
   with closing((psycopg2.connect(dbase='db', user='zzz')))as conn:
           ...
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think the connection object returned by the `connect` factory function doesn't have `__enter__` and `__exit__` ? If that were true, it would mean (a) `psycopg2` is not actually implementing DB-API 2 as claimed but nobody has ever noticed, and (b) your `with` statement should raise an `AttributeError` or `TypeError` but somehow a bug in the interpreter prevented that from happening.

Comment: And it took only a few seconds to find [the implementation in the source](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/master/psycopg/connection_type.c#L1149).

Comment: Anyway, there's no way to check if a function could return a context manager object, because any function could return anything. You can use static type annotations/typesheds and check with Mypy, but that doesn't help at runtime, and can't actually prove a function doesn't return some subclass of the expected type that adds context management.

Comment: But this is Python. If your code is too dynamic to look up the static answer in the docs or find it by exploration, you don't want to LBYL-test it, you want to just EAFP it: call the function, then pass the result to a helper that does a `try` and falls back to `closing` in the `except` clause, and `with` the call to that helper.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.